# How to get average time per status

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a history table(without primary_key) like this

```
id status     change_time (timestamp as bigint)
1  FINISH      165895464
1  PENDING     165695464
1  NEW         165495464
2  PENDING     166695464
2  NEW         166495464
3  NEW         165695464
```

My main goal is to get the average time per status change divided by the distinct number of ids.

Comment: Please include the expected result for that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, write SQL as you are formulating.

The first `CTE` is only the data setup.

The second subquery calulates the time in an event by subtracting the time of the next state for the same `ID`. Note that the last event cant be calculated.

Finaly make your formula.

```
with dt as (
select * from ( 
values
(1,  'FINISH',      165895464),
(1,  'PENDING',     165695464),
(1,  'NEW',         165495464),
(2,  'PENDING',     166695464),
(2,  'NEW',         166495464),
(3,  'NEW',         165695464)
) as tab (id, status, change_time)),
dt2 as (
select 
  id, status, 
  lead(change_time) over (partition by id order by change_time) - change_time time_diff
from dt)
select avg(time_diff) / count(distinct id) as "average time per status change divided by the distinct number of ids"
from dt2
```

The first query with your sample data returns

```
id          status     time_diff   
----------- ---------- ----------- 
1           NEW        200000      
1           PENDING    200000      
1           FINISH                 
2           NEW        200000      
2           PENDING                
3           NEW
```

So the `AVG` *time in status* is `200000`.

Divided through 3 (distinct `id` count) you get 66666.66

Comment: how to achieve the following result?
  
`FINISH  778(avg_time_per_status)
PENDING 687(avg_time_per_status)
NEW 5568(avg_time_per_status)
`

Comment: Well, *not easy* with your posted data - see my update @TarasDanylchenko

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like ths. `avg_weighted_time` is an "interval" in the same units as `change_time`.

```sql
select id, 
       nullif(max(change_time) - min(change_time), 0) / (count(*) - 1)
       / (select count(distinct id) from the_table) as avg_weighted_time
from the_table
group by id order by id;
```

| id | avg_weighted_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 66666 |
| 2 | 66666 |
| 3 | [null] |

If you need a single average for all id-s then

```sql
select sum(tp) / count(distinct id) 
from (
 select id,
   change_time - lag(change_time) over (partition by id order by change_time) tp 
 from the_table
) t;
```